# SQL Server: return placeholder / text if Left Join has no result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join, left-join

I am using Left Joins on a self-referenced table to see if an item has a parentID and then fetch the corresponding itemName of the parent. 
The parentID can be an integer or NULL.

My query works as intended. 
I am just wondering if there is a way I can return a placeholder / text (e.g. "---") as otherwise it just returns nothing for this specific part of the query. Maybe by using a Case statement ?

The parts in question are `E.itemName` and `D.itemName` as both are only available if `D.parentID` resp. `A.parentID` are not NULL.

**My procedure (shortened):**

```
SELECT      A.itemName,
            B.lastUpdate,
            B.modTime,
            B.modBy,
            E.itemName AS levelMain,
            D.itemName AS levelSub
FROM        MOC_Links A
LEFT JOIN   MOC_Log B
ON          B.itemID = A.itemID
LEFT JOIN   MOC_Links D
ON          D.itemID = A.parentID
LEFT JOIN   MOC_Links E
ON          E.itemID = D.parentID
WHERE       A.itemName LIKE '%'+@searchTerm+'%'
ORDER BY    itemName, levelMain
FOR XML PATH('results'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(E.itemName, '---') as levelMain
coalesce(D.itemName, '---') as levelSub
```

Comment: Perfect, yes that's exactly it - thanks a lot, Gordon ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Isnull, e.g. `ISNULL(E.itemName, '----')`